# Как создать массив обобщенных (Generic) объектов (классов) в Java

Tags: java, массивы, intellij-idea, generics, шаблоны

Собственно есть шаблонный класс `Pair` (насколько я знаю, в Java нет уже готовой реализации; если это не так поправте меня):

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    public Pair(T1 value1, T2 value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public T1 getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public T2 getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    private final T1 value1;
    private final T2 value2;
}
```

И мне нужно создать массив объектов этого класса. Делаю я это так:

```
Pair<String, String>[] examples = new Pair[arraysSize];
```

И всё вроде бы компилируется и даже работает, но вот IntelliJ кидает мне предупреждение

> Unchecked assignment: 'com.myClass.Pair[]' to 'com.myClass.Pair<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>[]'

Попытки дописать хоть куда-то `<>` не привели к результатам.

**Собственно вопрос: в чем проблема и как правильно создать массив обобщенных объектов?**

Comment: Добавьте сюда `new Pair[arraysSize];` знаки `<>` что бы было так `new Pair<>[arraysSize];`.

Comment: @Tsyklop я же говорю, _Попытки дописать хоть куда-то <> не привели к результатам._. Если написать так, как ты предлагаешь (`Pair<String, String>[] examples = new Pair<>[arraysSize];`), то среда выдаст ошибку: "*Cannot infer arguments*". А если скомпилировать, то java напишет: "*cannot create array with '<>'*"

Comment: а вы уверены, что нужен именно массив и нельзя использовать List? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18581313/4908529 Если ответ "да", то для упрощения себе жизни стоило бы сделать конечный класс на основе дженерика `class PairString extends Pair<String, String>` и массив делать уже из элементов `PairString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с `type erasure`.
Дело в том, что после компиляции дженерики "пропадают". Где бы вы не добавили `< >`,

```
Pair<String, String>[]
```

по сути превратится в

```
Pair[]
```

Пример с вашим классом:

```
@Test
public void typeErasure() {
    Pair<String, String>[] arr = new Pair[10];

    arr[0] = stringPair();
    arr[1] = integerPair();

    System.out.println(arr[0].getClass());
    System.out.println(arr[1].getClass());
}

Pair stringPair() {
    return new Pair<String, String>("s1", "s2");
}
Pair integerPair() {
    return new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1, 2);
}
```

Этит код сгенерирует много предупреждений, но в итоге скомпилируется и исполнится без ошибок. Результат:

```
class Test$Pair
class Test$Pair
```

Как видите, информация о типах T1, T2 отсутствует.

В итоге: создать действительно дженерик массив нельзя. Лучше используйте `List`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ и наглядный пример ошибки =)

Answer (score 2):

Да, идея предупреждает о таком и даже специально для этого придумали аннотацию - в вашем случае она выглядит как `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`; Как бы говоря компилятору: расслабься, так надо.)

Ссылка на доки: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html